# Landscape in VS Designer

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm testing Mono for Android and would create a TableView which always set in Landscape. The designer in VS first showing Landscape but after next opening the .axml file, I get always Portrait style and can't switch to Landscape.

Peter Artelt

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your device has `Landscape` and `Portrait` "configurations".

Look at the "7in WSVGA (Tablet)" as an example.

Then you can pick the "config" (Landscape or Portrait) in the designer's toolbar.